# What is the technical term for all variables/members of a class that are only for internal purpose?

Tags: c++

Is there a technical word commonly used by programmers to speak about variables and members of C++ classes that are only here for internal purpose (like some protected static const) and should not be used by the final user ?

Comment: What you're describing sounds like "private".

Comment: "implementation details" perhaps, but this is not so technical.

Comment: I'm not searching for a C++ keyword, but for a generic programming term like "Abstract class", "Helper class" etc...

Comment: thats "private" - for example pimpl idiom is short for "Private Implementation"

Comment: @luskan PIMPL = Pointer to IMPLementation

Comment: Perhaps you mean the term subsystem in the context where clients only see a wrapper of the internals. The facade design pattern is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the word you're searching for is [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29), which is one of the four buzz words they teach you about object-oriented programming in college (the other three being inheritance, polymorphism, and abstraction).

Comment: 'encapsulation' is not a buzz word, it's an important approach for managing complexity (in any programming paradigm, not just OOP).

Comment: All four of the words I mentioned name important approaches to managing complexity.  That doesn't make them any less buzzy.  They're the kind of words that too many hiring managers use in quizzing potential new hires on vocabulary rather than assessing their actual skills.  These kinds of interviews favor inexperienced developers who are fresh out of college and just finished taking tests on this kind of stuff, but who have no idea how to apply the concepts.  Seasoned developers have forgotten vocabulary words like these, but understand the concepts at a deeper level.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not discrediting the word, *per se*.  It's a perfectly good word that I've used myself on more than one occasion (probably most often in the verb form).  But the abstraction-encapsulation-inheritance-polymorphism mantra as a whole smacks of buzz.